# Indoor positioning

Tags: gps, indoor-positioning-system

I am trying to get indoor gps by trying to orient my floorplan with the actual building from google maps. I know perfect accuracy is not possible. Any idea how to do this ? Do the maps need to be converted to kml format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget that!

Only with luck you can get indoor GPS signals, probably only near the window, and then it is likely to be more distorted than the size of your building.

You only can try to get the coordinates outside, at the corner of the buildings.

For precise measures you would need some averaging of the measures, which only a few GPS devices offer. For less precision, take the coordinate, or measure it on differnet hours, days.

Comment: Agreed. "indoor" and "gps" don't fit in the same sentence, at least not currently.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, you should think about geolocation using Wifi/HF and any other wireless/radio sources that you can precisely locate since you probably install it yourself or at least someone from your company/service is responsible of them and could give you the complete list with coordinates. Then, once you've got the radio location, you can geolocate the devices using radio propagation and location.

I know that's not the answer you were looking for, but think about it as an alternate one if you really need to locate people inside your building.

PS: I did it at work and it works pretty well (except some areas where radio emitter are broken).